# Should I release NSData dataWithContentsOfURL?

Tags: ios, memory-management

Question on memory mgmt of the following:

```
NSData *returnData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]                                                options:0                                                     error:&err];
```

We are seeing our allocations spike here, but not sure if I should be releasing this memory after I have moved it off.

I get an exception when I try to release, so not understanding something about the internals here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No. It is returned `autorelease`d per naming convention.

You might check the memory management programming guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to release it.  The `dataWithContentsOfURL:` method returns an `autorelease` object.  It will be release automatically if you do not explicitly retain it.

Automatically, that is, so long as your current thread has an `NSAutoreleasePool` properly set up for it.  All `autorelease` objects are released when their enclosing `NSAutoreleasePool` is drained.  If you have found a leak in this code, then perhaps the corresponding pool is not being drained frequently enough (or perhaps not at all).